# Facebook PHP SDK v4 $session NULL after login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is my workflow. User goes to index.php and is redirected to Facebook to login. After logging in, they are redirected to post.php where I valid the `$session`. I was able to get this working locally, but as soon as I uploaded it to my server, the `$session` variable comes back `NULL`.

Here is my code from `post.php`.

```
session_start();

require_once("../assets/resources/constants.php");
require_once("autoload.php");


use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FACEBOOK_APP_ID,FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(BASE_URL."/facebook/post.php");

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  if (isset($session)) $_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    unset($session);
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

var_dump($session);
exit();
```

I did some digging around and was able to get this error thrown.

`object(Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException)#10 (10) { ["statusCode":"Facebook\FacebookRequestException":private]=> int(400) ["rawResponse":"Facebook\FacebookRequestException":private]=> string(190) "{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}" ["responseData":"Facebook\FacebookRequestException":private]=> array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(131) "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request" ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(100) } } ["message":protected]=> string(131) "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(100) ["file":protected]=> string(71) "/var/www/html/facebook/assets/sdk/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php" ["line":protected]=> int(104) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(62) "/var/www/html/facebook/assets/sdk/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php" ["line"]=> int(268) ["function"]=> string(6) "create" ["class"]=> string(33) "Facebook\FacebookRequestException" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(190) "{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}" [1]=> object(stdClass)#9 (3) { ["message"]=> string(131) "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request" ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(100) } [2]=> int(400) } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(74) "/var/www/html/facebook/assets/sdk/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php" ["line"]=> int(175) ["function"]=> string(7) "execute" ["class"]=> string(24) "Facebook\FacebookRequest" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [2]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(31) "/var/www/html/facebook/post.php" ["line"]=> int(32) ["function"]=> string(22) "getSessionFromRedirect" ["class"]=> string(36) "Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL }`

Comment: What version of php is installed on your production server?

Comment: @Andariel Production server has 5.4.39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue was caused by an extra `/` in my redirect_uri. Apparently it needs to match the one on Facebook exactly. Removing the extra slash fixed the issue.